# bzr-push / pull from emacs?

Tags: emacs, bazaar

I have been using bzr in emacs to commit changes using `M-x vv` and `C-c C-c`. However, I can't figure out how to push to the trunk using the emacs version control tools. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a push command in the Emacs integration. You can, however, alleviate the problem by using [bzr bound branches](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrUsingBoundBranches) - with the them commits will be automatically pushed.

AFAIK there will be significant improvements in the built-in Emacs VC mode in Emacs 24 and most of them will be related to DVCS such as bzr.